# Visual Studio 2019 16.3.6 ASP.NET Core Web Application project template does allow asp.net core version selection

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019

I've just updated Visual Studio 2019 to 16.3.6 which includes the ASP.Net Core 3 SDK.

I create a new project from the ASP.NET Core Web Application project template.  The previous version would let me pick the ASP.Net Core version (2,2.1,2.2).  Now it does not, and defaults to creating the project using ASP.Net Core 2.2, not 3.    Do I always need to manual upgrade every project I create or is there somewhat to bring back the version dropdown or set visual studio to default to Core 3?

**I've got Core 3.0 SDK installed:**
[image]

**Then I choose ASP.NET Core Web Application**
There are no other core related web projects to chose. Click Next
[image]

**Then I configure the project**  There are no options for version, or authentication.  I used to see those options prior to the upgrade.

[image]

Comment: The option appears on the next screen when you click on create.

Comment: WHAT?!?!  I swear that dialog did not appear for me. Or this is total pebcac!  Should I delete the question in embarrassment?

Comment: What do you get after clicking the `Create`? I upgrade to `16.3.6`, did not hit this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The option is still there. I think you need to install `.Net core 3 SDK`.

[image]

Comment: I don't see these options.  No MVC template either.  I've updated my question with screenshots.